# Chi squared test of association between socio-economic variables and multiple question-survey answers

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I have survey answers for a questionnaire that contains 8 separate questions, where each has a number of (categorical) choices, as well as data on the respondents' characteristics (age, professional status, etc..). The data is presented like this :

[image: data table]

where *hh* stands for household, *AGECHEF* for agegroup, and the *varc* variable is used to code the question and the answer to it (e.g. **Q860H** means that for **question 86, the answer given was "0H"**.) So *varc* records the answers to all questions.

(The dataset contains about 50k answers, the screenshot only shows the answers of *hh* no **10015** because *varc* has to take into account answers to each question, and some are multiple choice, so)

**My question is :** I want to **analyze the association between the answers and these socio-economic criteria**. If I were to use a **khi-2 test**, is it meaningful to use a cross table of *varc* and, say, *AGECHEF*? Or should I consider each question to be a separate variable with its own modalities (in which case I'd have to run 8 Chi-squared tests) ?

Any suggestions for a better way to go about this would very much be appreciated.

Comment: "is it meaningful to use a cross table of varc and, say, AGECHEF?" I don't see what practical conclusion you could draw from such a crosstable. Anyway, observations wouldn't be independent (as the same household could be counted multiple times in various cells of the crosstable), so it would violate one of the chi-square test assumptions. You're on the right track when you think about treating each question as its own variable, however it looks like some questions allow households to select multiple responses, so a chi-square test may be not the correct test to use for these questions.

Comment: On a side note, you should display your table in text format in your question, not as an image. Here is how to do that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: @JJJ Thank you so much for your answer, that clears it up for me. I will look further into the case of multiple-choice questions. As for table display, I'll  make sure to use text format in the future. Thanks.